# Updating the dependencies in a nix package

Tags: erlang, elixir, nix

Currently using the version of Elixir provided by the nix channel on Mac OS X.  The package was built with Erlang 18:

```
$ iex --version
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3.1.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

IEx 1.4.2
```

I'd like to update the package to use Erlang 19.  What's the most straightforward means of rebuilding a package in nix with updated dependencies?

Comment: Uninstall and install erlang one more time. I'm afraid there's no shortcut for that right now. Erlang is not mix dependency, but it's a layer you built on.

Comment: Indeed, you have to update the Erlang, if you are using brew, `brew update && brew upgrade erlang && brew cleanup erlang`

Comment: I believe this question was asked about the [nix package manager](https://nixos.org/nix/). Nothing to do with mix.

Comment: Correct.  I'd like to figure out the best way of doing this with nix.

Comment: Normally you achieve this by overriding the package like this `elixir.override { erlang = erlangR19; }` (cf. [the doc](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-modify-via-packageOverrides)). However, here it fails to build because some other dependencies need to be updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to arrive at a solution by adding the following package overrides to `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`:

```
{
  packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
    elixir = pkgs.elixir.override {
      erlang = pkgs.erlangR19_odbc_javac;
    };
    rebar = pkgs.rebar.override {
      erlang = pkgs.erlangR19_odbc_javac;
    };
  };
}
```

Overriding the elixir package wasn't sufficient to get the build working, as the build tool rebar was also built using Erlang 18.  Once that was specified, I ran `nix-env -i elixir` and the source for both packages was downloaded and built using Erlang 19.

One caveat: even with these changes to the `config.nix` nix insisted on downloading the Erlang 18 package.  However, this wasn't actually used in the build and was removed on running `nix-collect-garbage -d`.  Neither the rebar nor the elixir derivatives referenced the package so the cause remains a mystery.

Thanks to @zimm-i48 for the reference to the appropriate nix documentation.  Also useful was Luca Bruno's series of blog postings on nix:

http://lethalman.blogspot.it/2014/07/nix-pill-7-working-derivation.html